# Kernel patch command hangs

Tags: patch

I downloaded the 2.4.20 kernel sources and the ppc patch and have been 
 trying to apply the patch to the sources.  I place the 2.4.20 source 
 directory and the patch file in the same directory and command is 
`$patch -p1 {path/to/patch/file}.`.but prompt hangs there.

Answer (score 15):

Right, it expects input (patch content). You are supposed to redirect it to patch tool:

```
patch -p1 < /path/to/patch
```

Answer (score 4):

You can redirect in, or you can use the `-i` flag:

> -i PATCHFILE  --input=PATCHFILE  Read patch from PATCHFILE instead of stdin.